# General Topology, check my misunderstandings Half open topology is regular

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to solve some problems in Topology, but sometimes I run into trouble when I am trying to prove something, firstly I don't know if I am digging a whole and going nowhere or if I am on the right track.

For this question I need to
prove or disprove that $\mathbb{R}_{l}$ which is generated by the basis $\{ [a,b), a < b \}$ is regular

I choose to try to prove that it is correct..

$Proof$

Members of this base are open and closed thus the space is seperated, which means that for two open sets of the space $U \cap V = \emptyset$. Since the elements that generates the topology is open we can find a NB around each of its points, hence for some $x$ in the space there exists an open set $U$ around x.

Now suppose $K$ is a closed set in $R_{l}$ disjoint from x, then somehow I want to show that the open set $V$ that is disjont with the open set $U$ contains this closed set K, which I think will finish the proof?

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All basic sets $[a,b)$ are clopen (closed and open) so even complete regularity is immediate: use its characteristic function.

Explicitly, if $x \notin C$ and $C$ is closed find $y$ such that $x \in [x, y) \subseteq \Bbb R \setminus C$. Then $[x,y)$ and $\Bbb R \setminus [x,y)$ separate $x$ and $C$.

Comment: Thank you I will try to fiddle with it tomorrow, what do you mean when you say use its characteristic function?

Comment: @Jensens that’s for complete regularity not regularity.

Comment: okay thanks shouldn't your $\mathbb{R}$ be $\mathbb{R}_{l}$?

Comment: @Jensens I mean the set $\Bbb R$ (in the lower limit topology).

Comment: Okay so I think I cleared up my misunderstanding by looking at what you've said.     you pick some element not in the closed set because of the definition of being regular. and then you let x belong to a basic element without the closed set hence it is contained inside an open set, I suppose another way to see it is, every basis element is contained inside an open set? and it follows directly that the two sets are seperate, but how do I know that C is contained inside an open set that is disjoint from the open set containing x?

Comment: @Jensens Yes, if $x \in O$ and $O$ is open we have a basic set "in-between" $x$ and $O$ and I apply that to $x$ and $C^\complement$ (which is open, as $C$ is closed. As $[x,y) \subseteq C^\complement$ we immediately have the dual inclusion $C \subseteq [x,y)^\complement$ showing the separation of $x$ and $C$.

Comment: Thank you for your patience, I learned a lot